# JavaScript Dynamic naming with argument of function.

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic, naming

I have been looking around for an answer to this but in vain.

I have a function which takes a table name as an argument. but this name can be an object.

```
loadDataFromServer = function(dataTable) {
 //data fetch code ...
datadump[dataTable] = response.getDataTable();
}
loadDataFromServer(['gchart']['data'])
```

The problem is I need to store the data in a variable datadump.gchart.data but the "gchart.data" part needs to be determined upon calling the function, not hard coded in it. 
my problem lies in the fact that 
`datadump[['gchart']['data']]`    is not the same as 
`datadump['gchart']['data']`  (which is the same as `datadump.gchart.data`)

Does anybody here know a good way to do this? If the input was simply gchart_data, this would  easily work, but the functions needs to able to handle it even if it needed to assign its data to `blabla.blibli.bloebloe.stuff`.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered letting `loadDataFromServer` take an unbounded number of string arguments (`loadDataFromServer('gchart', 'data', ...)`), and iterating over them with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
function (result) {
    datadump = {};
    datadump.gchart = {};
    datadump.gchart.data = result.gchart.data;

    // or

    datadump.gchart = {
        data: result.gchart.data
    };    
}
```

It's a little bit strange to it like this though. Do you absolutely need the `gchart` in your `datadump`?

Assigning to a random depth like `blabla.blibli.bloebloe.stuff` is not easily done.

You could flatten like: `obj["blabla.blibli.bloebloe.stuff"] = {};`

Or you could write a recursive merge, like:

```
var a, b, c;
a = { foo: { ipsum: "lorem" } };
b = { bar: {}, foo: { abc: "def" } };
c = recursive_merge(a, b); // { foo: { ipsum: "lorem", abc: "def" }, bar: {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you function take a list of strings and iterate over them to recursively access (and, if necessary, create) properties of `datadump`. I use `arguments` here to use the list of arguments itself, but you could also just use a single argument that is an array of strings.

```
var loadDataFromServer = function() {
    var currObj = datadump;

    // iterate over the list of property names
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length - 1; ++i) {
        var nextName = arguments[i];

        // if the object doesn't have this property, make it
        if(currObj[nextName] == undefined) {
            currObj[nextName] = {};
        }

        // use currObj's property as the new `currObj`
        currObj = currObj[nextName];
    }

    // load data into the final named property
    currObj[arguments[i]] = response.getDataTable();
}

loadDataFromServer('gchart', 'data');
```